# JQuery mouseleave() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseleave

When I hover over the `div` element, the text enlarges however when the mouse leaves the `div`, the text stays the same size. I have tried `mouseenter()`, `mouseleave()` and `hover()` functions but nothing seems to work. Here is my code:
JQuery:

```js
function main() {
  page();
  $('.header h1').delay(2000).css('font-size', '50px');
  $('.header').mouseenter(function() {
 $('.header h1').css('font-size', '80px');
  });
  $('.header').mouseleave(function() {
 $('header h1').css('font-size', '50px');
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">

 <h1>Jacobsky</h1>

 <div class="navbar">

  <a onclick="page('home')">Home</a>

  <a onclick="page('info')">Information</a>

  <a onclick="page('about')">About Us</a>

  <a onclick="page('contact')">Contact Us</a>

  <a onclick="page('m_info')">More Info</a>

 </div>

</div>
```

The `onclick="page()"` is related to something else.
Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: I think that `$('header h1')` should be `$('.header h1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed the dot (.) in the `.header` class name

```
$('header h1')
```

Corrected code:

```
function main() {
  page();
  $('.header h1').delay(2000).css('font-size', '50px');
  $('.header').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.header h1').css('font-size', '80px');
  });
  $('.header').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.header h1').css('font-size', '50px');
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your mouseleave event you have used the wrong selector (you have used "header" instead of ".header"). Try this:

```
$('.header h1').css('font-size', '50px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have a typo in your selector it should be:

```
$('.header').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.header h1').css('font-size', '50px');
});
```